# Set JAVA_OPTS within the maven build step to inject JaCoCo agent

Tags: java, maven, cloud, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-business-technology-platform

I have a project that has has integration tests executed via maven-failsafe-plugin against locally deployed tomcat from SAP BTP SDK (https://tools.hana.ondemand.com). It is deployed and started via commands of the maven plugin.

The problem is that I cannot inject the JaCoCo agent there. Apparently, I can do it via JAVA_OPTS (I've seen the jacoco exec file appear if I set JAVA_OPTS in terminal), but cannot figure out how to set it from within the maven build (at pre-integration-test phase after JaCoCo agent is configured).

How can I do that?

Comment: I also tried cargo plugin, but I also cannot figure out how to use cargo only to start and stop the tomcat. I have it already setup and deployed everything when I start the tests.

Comment: Maybe this helps? [Reporting aggregated unit and integration test coverage with jacoco](https://natritmeyer.com/howto/reporting-aggregated-unit-and-integration-test-coverage-with-jacoco/)

Comment: Have you tried using the JaCoCo Maven Plugin? https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html
Moreover, you could try out the SAP Cloud SDK and its Maven archetypes to create a fresh project. They include already working integration test skeletons with JaCoCo. https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/getting-started (disclaimer: I work in the team who looks after the SAP Cloud SDK).